# Is there a tool that can perform a read-group-aware mpileup from a single file?

Tags: sam, samtools, pysam, mpileup

I would like to perform a `samtools mpileup` from a single file that contains thousands of read groups with different SM tags. I could split the bam by read group using `samtools split`, and then perform the mpileup, but splitting into thousands of files and then performing an mpileup from thousands of files is crazy slow on my machine.

I could imagine an implementation using pysam, but I was hoping someone has a solution already.

Bcftools mpileup already has this feature, but the feature was never implemented for the original mpileup format, which is what I need.

#### An example

Contents of `input.sam`:

```
@HD VN:1.6  SO:unknown
@SQ SN:chr1 LN:1000000
@RG ID:0    SM:sample_0
@RG ID:1    SM:sample_1
r0  0   chr1    24  0   1M  *   0   0   G   I   RG:Z:0
r1  0   chr1    24  0   1M  *   0   0   G   I   RG:Z:1
```

When I run samtools mpileup I get this behavior:

```
> samtools mpileup input.sam
[mpileup] 2 samples in 1 input files
chr1    24  N   2   ^!G$^!G$    II
```

Whereas, what I actually want is this output:

```
[mpileup] 2 samples in 1 input files
chr1    24  N   1   ^!G$    I   1   ^!G$    I
```

For a long time I thought this was a bug in samtools mpileup, but it appears that it is a feature that was described/hinted at in the samtools documentation, but was never implemented: https://github.com/samtools/samtools/issues/599#issuecomment-604941884

Comment: been a long time since i use that.. you need the RG tag field the reads right? mpileup uses this to separate into different columns (i.e samples)

Comment: Won't GATK handle this? At the very least the old unified caller required input exactly like this.

Comment: That's a really good point! I did not realize gatk has a Pileup command. Unfortunately, that command (I tested v4.1.7.0) is also not read group aware :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I broke down and finally scratched this itch. I have implemented a tool that performs read-group-aware text-pileup from a single SAM/BAM file. The tool is called [streaming_pileupy](https://pypi.org/project/streaming-pileupy/) and it's available from pypi for installation with pip. After installation the command would be:

```bash
spileup input.bam sample_names.txt
```

The tool is pre-alpha and missing some features. Contributions are welcome.